# How can I pass extra parameters to my custom test runner using Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

I'd like to pass extra parameters to my class extending `AndroidTestRunner` using Android Studio. I already know how to do it from the command line, but as far as I can tell, there's no way to do it using Android Studio up to version 1.4.

### Background

I have a class, `MyTestRunner` that looks like this:

```
public class MyJUnitRunner extends AndroidJUnitRunner {

    private final String TAG = "MyJUnitRunner";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle arguments) {
        super.onCreate(arguments);
        Log.i(TAG,arguments.toString());
    }
...
}
```

When I use this testrunner from the command line, I use a command something like this:

```
adb shell am instrument -w -r \
    -e debug false \
    -e foo bar \
    -e class espresso.test.MyTestClass \
    com.mycompany.myapp.test/espresso.runner.MyJUnitRunner
```

And I'll see this in the log file:

```
10-22 15:28:45.173 I/MyJUnitRunner( 5596): Bundle[{foo=bar, class=espresso.test.MyTestClass, debug=false}]
```

Notice that there is a "foo=bar" in the bundle that was added by the `-e foo bar` part of the `adb shell am instrument` command.

### Problem

As far as I can tell, there's no way to pass `-e key value` pairs to Android Studio.  There is an "Additional Command Line Options" parameter under the Emulator tab, but those are command line options for the emulator, not the test runner.

### UPDATES

*2015-10-26* I've created a feature request for this. If you found this question and are interested in seeing the same feature available, please click on the link below and star the issue. Please don't comment "me too!" or somewhere in the world a baby hippo will cry.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=191551

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a new feature of Android Studio 1.5.

[image: screenshot of Android Studio 1.5 showing Extra Options]

Comment: this is not in android studio 3.0, do you know where can I set it then?